# Poisson random measure with the uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(E,\cal E,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space
A poisson random measure with intensity $\mu$ is a map
$M:\Omega\times\cal E \rightarrow Z^{+}$
Denote $E^{*}$ the set of integer-valued measures on $\cal E$ and define

$X:E^{*} \times \cal E \rightarrow Z^{+}$

$X_{A}:E^{*} \rightarrow Z^{+}$, $A \in \cal E$

Theorem 7.1.3 
There exist a unique probability measure $\mu^{*}$ on $(E^{*},\cal E^{*})$ such
that $X$ is Poisson random measure with intensity $\mu$

The proof for uniqueness said

For disjoint sets $A_{1},\ldots,A_{k} \in \cal E$ and $n_{1},\ldots,n_{k} \in Z^{+}$ set 
$A^{*}=\{m \in E^{*}:m(A_{1})=n_{1},\ldots,m(A_{k})=n_{k}\}$

such of sets $A^{*}$ is a $\pi$-system generating $\cal E^{*}$

How we to verify this????

The attached website is the lecture

http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/6021110392b6ba43c1256f6a002d5f33/$FILE/AP7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't seem right to me. Consider $E = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 \}$ with its counting measure and subsets $\sigma$-algebra, we can consider the sets :

$$A_1 = \{ m, m( \{ 1, 2 \} ) = 2 \}$$
$$A_2 = \{ m, m( \{ 2, 3 \} ) = 2 \}$$

It seems to me that their intersection is not in $A^*$. This is not too hard to work out, and based on the fact that their intersection contains both the measures $m$ and $m'$ :

$$m( 1 ) = m( 2 ) = m( 3 ) = 1$$
$$m'( 1 ) = m'( 3 ) = 0, m'( 2 ) = 2$$

Which proves that the decomposition of $A_1 \cap A_2$ cannot contain conditions on singletons and on the whole space since $m$ and $m'$ disagree on all of them. So the decomposition may only involve doubles, but it is easy to check that the intersection is neither equal to $\{m, m(\{ 1, 2 \}) = 2\}$ or $\{m, m(\{ 2, 3 \}) = 2\}$.